# interpretation of conditional probability

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, conditional

São Paulo Futebol Clube probably wins 0.7 if it rains and 0.8 if it doesn't. In September the chance of rain is 0.3. São Paulo won a game in September, how likely was it to rain that day?

(A) Answer is: P(Rain | Win) = P(Rain And Win) / P(Win) = 0.7 * 0.3/0.7 * 03 + 0.7*0.8 ~ 0.27

(B) Otherwise P(Win | Rain) = 0.7

How I interpret A and B ?

(A): 27 times out of 100 it was raining when SPFC won ?
(B): 70 times out of 100 SPFC won when it was raining ?

I don't know, it sounds strange how I interpreted this. It seems the phrasing is the same... please help!

TKS

Comment: This sounds like a practice problem or homework problem. If so, please tag as [tag:self-study].

Comment: I found an article that says that 'A given B' could be rephrased as 'A within B' (set theory). So (A): 27 times out of 100 rained within the occasions SPFC won. So if he won 100 times, 27 victories were in raining days. (B): SPFC won 70 matches within 100 matches that rained. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/10691898.2006.11910584